# Mod Rewrite for Code Igniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a code igniter site that needs to accept incoming links in the format:

http://domain.tld/somename.html?id=IDREF

I need to create a rule for mod_rewrite that rewrites this URL to:

http://domain.tld/index.php/controller/somename/IDREF

I am having trouble writing the rule for the .htaccess file.

I thought this should work:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\.html\?id=.*)$

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html\?id=(.*) /index.php/controller/$1/$2 [L]
```

But as I am a bit of a novice at mod_rewrite I can't get it to work.

Just to clarify I want the user to link to this ugly url and get sent to specific controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^id=
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?id=(.*) index.php/controller/$1/$2 [L]
```

You might need to add a question mark after the second `$2` if you get the original query string appended somehow after the rewrite